# Show Tutorial only when application is running for the first time | ionic 3

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I got a little problem with my code.
I would like to show a tutorial only if the app is opened for the first time and when user goes on ‘25 foot walk’ page
Here is the code I tried:

```
export class Survey_25footPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
    if(localStorage.getItem['firstTimeLoad']!='TRUE'){
      localStorage.setItem['firstTimeLoad']='TRUE';
      this.navCtrl.setRoot(TutorialPage); 
  }
```

The tutorial (because it’s in constructor ?) is called everytime and when i skip the tutorial, it shows again…

What should I do to fix that ?
Thanks a lot for your time !

Comment: Which local storage you use? Ionic or standard browser one?

Comment: I use the ionic storage and i don't know if there is any kind of "First Time Load" property

Comment: Normally the syntax for getting an item out of ionic storage is the following: `storage.get('age').then((val) => {
    console.log('Your age is', val);
  });`... You might want to check the [docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/#usage)

Comment: So in your code you have Storage and localStorage its unclear where did you import the latter from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ionic Storage which methods are async, you need to leverage promises as was pointed in the comments:

```
export class Survey_25footPage {
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
    this.storage.get(“tutorialShown”).then( result => {
        if (!result) {
            this.storage.set(“tutorialShown”, true);
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(TutorialPage);
        } else {
            this.navCtrl.setRoot(HomePage);
        }
    })
  }
```